# Convert CJS to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

How can I convert these lines of code to ES6?

```
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to convert it to an ES6 module?

Comment: yes, can you help?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-import-json-files-in-es-modules-node-js/ https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-json-modules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything to ES6, it's perfectly valid ES6 - it just doesn't use any new features that were introduced in ES6 from my knowledge. You *could* use destructuring if you really wanted to:

```
const { env: config } = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json");
```

But ES6 is not a fancy new language, it's just got some new features you can use if you need them.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm using node.js, and I set type="module" so I can't use something like required() or module.exports because console says error "it's common.js".

Comment: So perhaps the commonjs documentation is a good place to look?